# Excel Values Uploading as NULL to database

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an Excel file in which I have many records. When I upload this file to a table in a database (SQL Server) some values save as NULL even though the Excel file does not have NULL or blank fields.

I double checked all data types of the columns to make sure they are of the correct data type but no luck.

However, I tried pasting the values in question into a Notepad file, and pasted  them back into the Excel from Notepad and this worked. The values no longer save as NULL if I do this.

1. What could be the reason this occurs? Why does the database not "see" these values in Excel?
2. Is there a quicker way I can check the data before uploading?

Comment: Entire rows of NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>*Answer originally left as comments*</sub>

This is a data type issue on Excel's side, and the file was probably created by someone else. By copying and pasting using Notepad, you're stripping all formatting and effectively converting the data types to strings. I'm betting it's a date field or a number that is being formatted in an odd way and the SQL implicit conversion is failing because of a leading apostrophe or something ridiculous. – [Randolph West](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/101326/randolph-west)

Unfortunately, importing Excel data is rife with difficulties like this. You'd be far better off to get the source data in another format such as CSV, or better yet, a binary format of some type. – [Max Vernon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon)